# Does 「拝見ありがとうございます」 ever make sense?

Tags: politeness, honorifics

I have seen this used on a Japanese site by at least two native speakers, usually attached to the end of the post to mean "Thank you for reading". The phrasing simply doesn't make sense to me. 「拝見」is 謙譲語. How could you thank someone for their 拝見? I commented that I didn't think it was correct to say that phrase and I essentially got snapped at.

I have found [this post](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14100690059) that reaffirms this, but I am curious if this locution would ever make sense.

---

Come to think of it, last time I told someone who included in their Japanese post the English line "Thank you for watching" that it should be "Thank you for reading" my suggestion wasn't exactly welcomed either...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

おっしゃる通り、「拝見ありがとうございます。」は敬語の使い方が間違っています。「拝見いただきありがとうございます。」「ご拝見ありがとうございます。」「拝見していただき...」などは、（言おうとしていることはわかるんですが、）どれもおかしいです。

「拝見」「拝読」「拝聴」などは謙譲語ですから、相手の行為には使いません。「ご覧くださりありがとうございます。」「ご覧くださってありがとうございます。」（または、「ご覧いただき...」。この「～いただき」は間違っているとの意見もありますが。）などと言うのが正しいと思います。

敬語は日本語母語話者にも難しいようで、結構多くの人が間違えて使っていたり、間違えて覚えていたりします。私も、何かしら間違って使ってしまっているんだろうなと思いますが...。